# Format phone number in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In the application I am working on, I have a TableAdapter, and a RadGridView (Telerik control - their version of the DataGridView).  The TA is pulling different elements from our database, including PhoneNumber, which is stored as varchar.

In my GridView, I would like to display this format as (123) 456-7890.  Unfortunately, I have been unable to accomplish this.

I have tried the following (which is Telerik's recommended method):

```
radGvUsers.Columns["PhoneNumber"].FormatString = "{0: (###) ###-####}";
```

This results in the value displaying as it does in the db: 1234567890

I know (ok, I think) this is because it is stored as varchar and needs to be converted to a number, but I don't know how or where (i.e. at the TA or GridView level) best to do this.

Any suggestions?  Feel free to ask more questions if I did not supply enough info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the string to a numeric in the SQL Statement

```
Select Convert(bigint, PhoneNumber) AS PhoneNumber FROM sometable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do like below. No need to get data as string from database.

```
radGvUsers.Columns["PhoneNumber"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "(###) ###-####";
```